# Python: Tensorflow PNG encoding

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, encoding

I'm trying to figure out the reason, why this code snippet returns False:

```
decodedBase64 = tf.io.decode_base64(imgBase64)
decodedBase64==tf.io.encode_png(tf.io.decode_png(decodedBase64))
```

A png image can be compressed and decode_png detects it, so I used different 'compression=' values in encode_png. I still got False with all values between -1 to 9.

What can be done to retrieve correct decodedBase64 characteristics to make encode_png <-> decode_png reversible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with tensorflow and your code is not runnable to be able to try it, so I may well be wrong and will delete my answer if so. I also think that the base64 encoding and decoding is something of a red herring. I think you are actually asking why you get a different PNG from one you already have when you encode with tensorflow. If so, there are several possible reasons:

- the date and time may be encoded in the PNG so if you write a PNG and then write it again with the same compression 1 second later, it will differ if that is the case
- the original PNG might have been created with a different library, a different version or different parameters, and although you will get the same pixels back because the encoding is lossless, the encoded data on disk could differ. For example, one library might choose a different filter for some rows - or no filter at all

Of course, if you want a definitive rather than speculative answer, you'd need to share the 2 PNGs - unmodified.